# Specifying fixed number of ticks in plot in R

Tags: r

Let's say that we have two vectors following.

```
x<-1:30
y<-rnorm(30)
```

I want then plot a graphs y~x with ticks at levels : 0,6,12,18,24,30 (at x axis) and y[0],y[6],y[12],y[18],y[24],y[30] (at y axis), but I have one problem) :

**For x axis :**

```
plot(x,y,type='l',xaxt='n',yaxt='n')
axis(1, at=seq(0,30,by=6))
```

**For y axis**

Now I had a problem, because I want to have ticks at levels :

```
y[0]
y[6]
y[12]
y[18]
y[24]
y[30]
```

And I'm not sure how code it within the axis function.

Comment: do you mean `axis(2, at = y[seq(0,30,by=6)])` ?

Comment: That's the likely solution, just remember R isn't 0-indexed so there is no `y[0]`.

Comment: Thank's! So simple ;))

Comment: Also, since `y` isn't sorted, these are not quantiles, just random values of `y`, so you might want `sort(y)[seq...`